# Using express middle ware and passing res.local data to routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to set up a securitycheck middleware that will run on the routes i add it to.

**Middleware**

```
function SecurityCheckHelper(req, res, next){
  apiKey = req.query.apiKey;
  security.securityCheck(apiKey).then(function(result) {
      res.locals.Security = result.securitycheck;
      console.log(res.locals.Security);
  });
  return next(); // go to routes

};
```

**Route**

```
app.get('/settings', SecurityCheckHelper,function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(res.locals);
});
```

Its relatively straight forward I'm trying to pass `result.securitycheck` (which return true/false) into the `/settings` route. However `res.locals` is returning an empty object

Comment: This is because your securityCheck is async, and your returning next instantly..  put the next inside your then..

Comment: @Keith Awesome! you nailed it on the head, could you answer the question so i can give you credit :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calling next before you have run your securityCheck.

IOW: the next middleware is getting processed before you securityCheck has finished processing. securityCheck is async,.

Placing your next inside your then, will wait until the securityCheck has finished.

eg.

```
function SecurityCheckHelper(req, res, next){
  apiKey = req.query.apiKey;
  security.securityCheck(apiKey).then(function(result) {
      res.locals.Security = result.securitycheck;
      console.log(res.locals.Security);
      next();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to interface security check promise with the callback.

```
function SecurityCheckHelper(req, res, next){
  apiKey = req.query.apiKey;
  security.securityCheck(apiKey)
  .then(function(result) {
      res.locals.Security = result.securitycheck;
      console.log(res.locals.Security);
      return next();
  })
  .catch(err => next(err));
};
```

Comment: I like the addition of the .catch! thanks! i awarded the answer to keith because he answered it first :) thank you for you help though!